# How to use <username> in detailview for django 2.0

Tags: python, django

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('userprofile:to_profile', args=[str(self.user.username)])
```

So I have made this model to save it as whatever.com/userprofile:to_profile/thisisusername

And on url, I have

```
    path('accounts/profile/<username>/', ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name="to_profile"),
```

For the view, I have

```
class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):
model = Profile
template_name = "account/profile.html"
```

I do know that default DetailView takes pk and slug but whenever I try to pass the username with

```
pk_url_kwarg = "username"
```

I get an error

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

Is there anyway we can use username for generic detailview? or is pk the only way to go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things you will need to do:

First change your URL's to:

```
path('accounts/profile/<str:slug>/', ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name="to_profile"),
```

Second define the method to get the SlugField

```
class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = "account/profile.html"

    def get_slug_field(self):
    """Get the name of a slug field to be used to look up by slug."""
        return 'user__username'
```

Comment: You can also set `slug_field = "user__username"` instead of overriding `get_slug_field`.

Comment: It is true Alasdair, I just tested here and both works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t use `pk_url_kwarg` because `username` is not the primary key of the `Profile` model that you are displaying in the view.

Override `get_object` instead.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def get_object(self):
    return get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=self.kwargs['username'])
```